# Equivalent of where clause in indexeddb

Tags: where-clause, indexeddb

Let's assume we got a database for todolist and want to query all item that are important and are not already done. In SQL, I will use something like

```
SELECT * FROM todolist WHERE important = true AND state <> 'done'
```

How can we perform that type of request in an indexeddb nosql database?
With indexes?
Another way?
Not possible?

As I know to filter result on `important = true` :

```
objectstore.index('important').openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only('true'))
```

But I do not know how to filter on `state <> 'done'` as we got only `IDBKeyRange.only(z)`.

And I do not know how to filter on both clause.

N.B. : In MongoDB we do :

```
db.userdetails.find({"date_of_join" : "16/10/2010","education":"M.C.A."})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In IndexedDB, is there a way to make a sorted compound query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query)

Comment: Checkout this library [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/tutorial/where)

Comment: If you want to use sql query for indexeddb, check out sqlweb - http://jsstore.net/tutorial/sqlweb/

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You will need indexes for that, and you can retrieve the data using a cursor where you can provide one filter.

On my blog (http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/01/indexed-db-reading-multiple-records.html?m=1) you can find some more info about it.

Comment: I need more details to success with your answer. I can filter result with `objectstore.index('important').openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only('true'))` which filter only on `important = true`. But I do not know how to filter on `state <> 'done'` as we got only `IDBKeyRange.only(z)`. And so I do not know how to filter on both clause.

Comment: If you want to filter on multiple properties, the best way to do this, is retrieve all records from the object store and in the cursor method you keep an array with the results in where you only add the objects that fit the given condition. If you hate doing this all on your own, you can maybe look for a library that allready implements these possibilities. I've written one called linq2indexeddb (http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com).

Comment: Ok, that was my other idea : retrieve everything then filter with a 'if' clause. And I would look at solution with linq. Thank you.

Comment: Your link is broken, which is why it's best to put the actual answer as opposed to a link.

Answer (score 6):

In onupgradeneeded, create an index on the criteria that uses an array:

```
todolistStore.createIndex('importantIncomplete', ['important','state'],{unique:false});
```

For your query do:

```
var lowerBound = ['true','started'];
var upperBound = ['true','almostdone'];
var range = IDBKeyRange.bound(lowerBound,upperBound);
var request = todolistStore.index('importantIncomplete').openCursor(range);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this upper and lower bound are supposed to be... for example, what if you want to search for not in the "blocked" state?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to query multiple indexes in IndexedDB. Josh described the fastest way of querying multiple fields using composite index. However it has cost of storage and slow down writing. Additionally query must be known a priori and hence index are created as required. Second method is manual key joining using sorted merge or others algorithm. This method requires indexes (not composite) on fields of interested and work all combination query. See here http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html for sorted merge, nested loop and zigzag merge implementation in ydn-db library. I attend to add more key joining algorithms.

BTW, generally we don't index boolean value. If your query field is boolean data type, just do table scan. Not point in using index.