# Indexed DB cursor ranges on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a composite index of two properties on an indexeddb objectstore and wish to retrieve a cursor based on the range of both of these properties.

Here's an example object in the store :

```
{species: 'Oak',xcoord: 123456, ycoord: 654321}
```

and index :

```
treeStore.createIndex("treelocation", ["xcoord","ycoord"], { unique: false });
```

The index creation is succesful and I can see it in the Chrome developer tools, however now I'd like to open a cursor with a keyrange on both the x and y co-ordinates (which will be the extent of a map).

Searching online I can't see how to do this, and opening an index with an array of key ranges doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `IDBKeyRange.bound([lowX,lowY],[highX,highY])` ? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks Meryn - that was it, if you'd like to post as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Hmmm must be my lucky day! :) I have posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been told the solution is indeed `IDBKeyRange.bound([lowX,lowY],[highX,highY])`.

Comment: This will not behave as you might expect.

The range `IDBKeyRange.bound([2,2], [4,4])` includes values like [3,0] and [3,5] as [2,2] < [3,0] < [3,5] < [4,4] per the definition of keys (https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct)

Which is to say, you will need to do additional filtering, as this solution on its own is insufficient. e.g. if the key [x,y_less_than_min] is seen, ignore it and advance the cursor with `continue([x,lowY])`; if the key [x,y_greater_than_max] is seen, ignore it and advance the cursor with `continue([x+1, lowY])`

Answer (score 8):

The range suggestion is part of the answer, but even with array keys it really is just a 1-dimensional range, not a 2- (or N-) dimensional selection of the data. With your current schema you'll need to do something like this:

```
index.openCursor([lowX, lowY], [highX, highY]).onsuccess = function(e) {
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if (!cursor) return; // done!

    var x = cursor.key[0], y = cursor.key[1];
    // assert(lowX <= x && x <= highX);
    if (y < lowY) {
        cursor.continue([x, lowY]);
    } else if (y > highY) {
        cursor.continue([x + 1, lowY]);
    } else {
        processRecord(cursor.value); // we got one!
        cursor.continue();
    }
};
```

(if coordinates are not integral, replace `+ 1` with an appropriate epsilon)

I've posted an example of a generalized solution to:

https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/704e9688f99ac12dd336

Comment: Is this still the best approach?  Trying to find items in a plane that are inside of a bounding box, starts to get slow when # items is 100k+. Does adding more than 1 to `x` work?  Something like `continue([x + boundsDiff, lowY])`? (sorry for necro)

Comment: As noted, the key space is one dimensional. Calling `continue([x+n, /*anything*/])` will skip over any items with a first array entry less than `x+n` that haven't been visited yet

Answer (score 4):

The index you created is a composite index. It is query like this:

```
index = objectStore.index('treelocation');
index.get([123456, 654321]);
```

Alternatively, you can use two indexes for each coorrd. In my opinion it is better.

```
x_index = objectStore.index('xcoord'); 
y_index = objectStore.index('ycoord');
x_species = x_index.get(IDBKeyRange.only(123456)) 
y_species = y_index.get(IDBKeyRange.only(654321)) 
species = x_species.intersect(y_species); // this is result
```

Comment: Thanks Kyaw - this would be a great solution if I only wanted to retrieve records at one location, however the x and y are geographic co-ordinates and I'm looking to retrieve a range of both as one get,  hence the composite index.