# Javascript IndexedDb: searching a range of value using multiple keys

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is it possible to search an indexedDb object store with a "bound" keyRange on multiple keys. With the following data:

```
  let simpleA = {
    id: 'A',
    bottomX: 2.5,
    bottomY: 5.5,
    topX: 3.5,
    topY: 6.5
  };

  let simpleB = {
    id: 'B',
    bottomX: 4.2,
    bottomY: 4.2,
    topX: 4.8,
    topY: 4.8
  };

  let simpleC = {
    id: 'C',
    bottomX: 8.5,
    bottomY: 6.5,
    topX: 9.5,
    topY: 7.5
  };
```

I have tried to create a index on multiple keys:

```
simpleStore.createIndex('bottomX bottomY topX topY', ['bottomX', 'bottomY', 'topX', 'topY']);
```

and a key range like this:

```
let keyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(
      [0,5,0,0],
      [10,6,10,10]
);
```

And then creating a cursor:

```
let mycursor = index.openCursor(keyRange);
```

I was hoping that this would give me a result of `simpleA` and `simpleB` but not `simpleC`, because the bottomY property is not in the range. However, as I tested this code, I realized that only the first key of the index is tests with the `bound` keyrange.

**Is there another way to achieve this range search on multiple keys?**

For infos, I got the inspiration of the multiple index from this post:
[Javascript: Searching indexeddb using multiple indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501459/javascript-searching-indexeddb-using-multiple-indexes)

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually combine all four individual key range queries.

IndexedDB query support varying only the last key. For example, the following query will work.

```
let keyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(
      [0,5,10,0],
      [0,5,10,10]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question you're asking is equivalent to:

[Indexed DB cursor ranges on mulitiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522115/indexed-db-cursor-ranges-on-mulitiple-properties)

Which is to say, you're trying to do query bounded by multiple dimensions. Indexed DB queries are (currently) limited to ranges, and ranges are 1-dimensional. So the range start [s1, s2] = [0, 0, 0] to end [e1, e2] = [2, 2] includes value [v1, v2] = [1, 3] because s1 <= v1 <= e1, so v2 isn't considered.

There's a solution linked to from that article.