# IndexedDB IN clause equivalent

Tags: indexeddb, web-sql

In WebSQL, I have this code

```
tx.executeSql('select * from TABLE where FIELD IN (? ,? ,?) ;', ['REGULAR', 'FULL' , 'CONTRACTUAL' ])
```

Is there a similar construct in IndexedDB?  I was looking at the IDBKeyRange.bound but just would like to make sure that it will match up.

Comment: Is this possible in IndexedDB or is there any workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OR or IN operation in IndexedDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419703/or-or-in-operation-in-indexeddb)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform the equivalent of `field = value1 or field = value2` in indexedDB.

Off the top of my head, here is a workaround. Use integer constants to represent the categories of FIELD. For example, 1 for REGULAR, 2 for FULL, and 3 for CONTRACTUAL. Order the constants such that the numbers are consecutive.  Then use IDBKeyRange with lower bound on the lowest desired constant and upper bound on the highest constant.