# Querying an IndexedDB compound index with a shorter array

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

IndexedDB allows you to make indexes on multiple properties. Like if you have objects like `{a: 0, b: 0}` you can make an index on `a` and `b`.

The behavior of compound indexes is [pretty weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625231/786644), but apparently it is supposed to be possible to query with an array that is shorter than the compound index. So in my example, I should be able to query on something like `[0]` and get results for a==0.

But I can't seem to get that to work. Here's an example which [you can run on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/megaranehuja/1/):

```
var db;

request = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
request.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  var store = db.createObjectStore("store", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
  store.createIndex("a, b", ["a", "b"], {unique: true});

  store.add({a: 0, b: 0});
  store.add({a: 0, b: 1});
  store.add({a: 1, b: 0});
  store.add({a: 1, b: 1});
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  db = request.result;
  db.onerror = function (event) { console.log(event); };

  console.log("Only [0, 0]");
  db.transaction("store").objectStore("store").index("a, b").openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only([0, 0])).onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
      console.log(cursor.value);
      cursor.continue();
    } else {
      console.log("Any [0, x]");
      db.transaction("store").objectStore("store").index("a, b").openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only([0])).onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          console.log(cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        }
      };
    }
  };
};
```

[Here is the JS Bin link again.](http://jsbin.com/megaranehuja/1/)

The output I see is:

```
Only [0, 0]
Object {a: 0, b: 0, id: 1}
Any [0, x]
```

But I was hoping to see:

```
Only [0, 0]
Object {a: 0, b: 0, id: 1}
Any [0, x]
Object {a: 0, b: 0, id: 1}
Object {a: 0, b: 1, id: 2}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use key range `IDBKeyRange.bound([0], [0, ''])`, so that all keys started with `[0]` included.

Comment: That does work, but I don't think I understand why. Isn't `bound` supposed to compare as >= and <=?

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more general version of Kyaw Tun's answer: if all keys are known to be arrays with two non-array elements, and you want the ones matching `[x, <any>]`, use `IDBKeyRange.bound([x], [x, []])`.

Comment: cheers @Ivan! that's exactly what was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain why Ivan's (and Kyaw's too) answer does work: **values of different type can be compared**.

Only if you're sure that you are comparing **numbers** you can use `IDBKeyRange.bound([x], [x, MAX_NUMBER])` (if *b<MAX_NUMBER*) or `IDBKeyRange.bound([x], [x, ''])` but in general case (assumed without array subkeys) you have to put an empty array (`[]`) as upper bound for the *b* subkey.

From [W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct)  :

> Number keys are less than date keys. Date keys are less than string
> keys. String keys are less than binary keys. Binary keys are less than
> array keys