# How to create an indexeddb composite key

Tags: indexeddb, composite-primary-key

I spent hours and hours searching for this one, and just by trial and error was I able to finally find the solution. Logging this in Stack Overflow for future searchers.

**Q:**

How do I create a composite key in indexeddb?

Keys are created in indexeddb on object stores using the following:

```
var db;
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('myDB', 1);
openRequest.addEventListener('error', () => {
    console.error('Unable to open db');
});
openRequest.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', function(event){
    var store = db.createObjectStore('myStore', 
        {keyPath: /* composite key */ }
    );
});
openRequest.addEventListener('success', function(){
    db = openRequest.result;
});
```

I have tried placing objects, defining multiple times, how does one create a composite key, or is this a limitation of the API?

**Note:** If you are looking for how to *query* a composite key using a range, please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query) post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In IndexedDB, is there a way to make a sorted compound query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query)

Comment: @Josh Though the referenced post does talk about a composite index, it is primarily focused on the IDBKeyRange in selecting a range of elements. The post also does not explain how to create a composite primary key for an Indexeddb object store and therefore I believe this post to not be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, definitely not a duplicate. This is about _creating_ (and populating) an object store using a compound `keyPath`; the referenced topic is about _extracting_ items from such a store. The two complement each other very effectively. Together, they're very helpful; as SnareChops says, this is not well documented (even four years later!).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer is very simple, but not documented well anywhere I have looked, and not obvious at first glance. Use an array of strings...

```js
var store = db.createObjectStore('myStore', 
    {keyPath: ['id1', 'id2']}
);
```

Composite indexes can also be created in the same fashion.

For work with composite key data, [see the answer below by Malvineous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67239319/1905476)

Comment: The array elements don't have to be strings; numeric values work just as well.

Comment: @Velojet those strings are property names, not the values of the key. However, if you would pass such an array to `put`, then it is the value of the keys.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @rudolfbyker. I should make it clear that I'm referring to a composite key array in the context of a `put` operation: `db.put(storename, item, [var1, var2])` where `var1` and `var2` are numeric values. My essential point still stands, that while the composite key itself can be an array, it doesn't have to be an array of _strings_.

Comment: @snareChops Thanks for the Q&A, I'm unable to find any example or documentation on how to retrieve data based on this composite key. Like I want to find all records with id1 and extract the last record from the set. Can you please help on this ? I'm adding like row1 => [id1 = abc & id2 = 1], row2 => [id1 = abc & id2 = 2]

Comment: @Bsienn See the answer below that Malvineous just posted

Comment: @SnareChops Love this community, thanks for the update. Though I already had figured it out. cheers

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to this, to actually use a composite key, it's not that clear either.

Adding an object isn't too bad:

```
myStore.add({
    id1: 'a',  // first part of key
    id2: 'b',  // second part of key
    etc: 'c',  // other data to store
});
```

However getting the object again using the composite key isn't all that obvious.  You need to pass an array as the key, with the values in the same order as the `keyPath` array originally passed to `createObjectStore()`.

```
myStore.get(['a', 'b'])   // look for id1=a + id2=b
```

Here, the first value in the array (`a`) matches up with `keyPath[0]` which in the above answer is set to `id1`.