# How to do "select * from table where indexA >= 'a' order by indexB ASC limit 10" in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Currently I am learning about javascript IndexedDB, and I found I cannot do complicated query when I use it. Now I want to make a select query like
`"select * from table where indexA >= 'a' order by indexB ASC limit 10"`

I tried to use
 
`store.createIndex("indexA, indexB", ["indexA","indexB"])`
 
and tried to make request like
`store.index("indexA, indexB").openCursor(IDBKeyRange.lowerBound([1, "a"], true))`
however the result only ordered according to indexA. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177 helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to roll this yourself. There are basically two approaches:

- Use an index on 'indexA' as you've done, open a cursor with lower bound 'a' and iterate, accumulate all the results, then sort by indexB, and pick the first 10.
- Use an index on 'indexB', open a cursor and iterate, skipping any entries where indexA < 'a', and stop after 10 are encountered.

The linked topic (thanks, other Josh!) provides more detail.