# IndexedDB's multi-query is weird

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I did `.createIndex('abcIDX', ['A', 'B', 'C'])`.

However, I felt the results were strange, so I did the following tests.

```js
// All methods except "IDBKeyRange.only()" are weird.;
const range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound( [5,5,5] );

function test( arr ) {
  console.log( range.includes(arr) );
}

test([5,5,5]); // case1: true
test([5,5,1]); // case2: false
test([5,6,1]); // case3: true ?
test([6,1,1]); // case4: true ??
test([1,6,1]); // case5: false ??
```

I thought `IDBKeyRange` works as `A && B && C`.

Cases 1 and 2 were right.

But cases 3 and 4 were not. So I guessed it works with `||`, not `&&`.

However, cases 2 and 5 showed that the speculation was wrong.

Stackoverflow had a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query). Here's what I understand after reading this answer.

> It's work `A || (A && B) || (A && B && C)`.

However, case 2 showed that the speculation was wrong.

What am I wrong with? Or am I using it wrong? Help me plz...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In IndexedDB, is there a way to make a sorted compound query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084177/in-indexeddb-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sorted-compound-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison may be easier to understand if you map numbers to characters, and think of string comparisons. A=1, B=2, E=5, F=6. So [5,5,5] is "EEE"

```
range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound( [5,5,5] ); // think of this as "EEE"

test([5,5,5]); // case1: "EEE" >= "EEE" ? true
test([5,5,1]); // case2: "EEA" >= "EEE" ? false
test([5,6,1]); // case3: "EFA" >= "EEE" ? true
test([6,1,1]); // case4: "FAA" >= "EEE" ? true
test([1,6,1]); // case5: "AFA" >= "EEE" ? false
```

The actual logic is basically:

```
((test[0] >  range[0])) ||
((test[0] == range[0]) && (test[1] >  range[1])) ||
((test[0] == range[0]) && (test[1] == range[1]) && (test[2] >= range[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you. understand.
So, is it not possible to multi-query each field A, B, C where numeric values are stored?
Cases 3 and 4 are still weird when the range of values needs to be numbers. :(

Comment: Correct. Key space is linear. You may find https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/704e9688f99ac12dd336 helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed answer. :)